# Wordpress: how to remove/prevent unwanted languages

Tags: wordpress

on all my WP installations it updates (download) language packs for unwanted languages, is there a way (any) to tell WP to only update a selected few languages instead?

Answer (score 5):

You can delete unwanted languages from /wp-content/languages/ plugins and themes. WP will stop updating all languages that you have completely deleted.